# Evaluating minimal polynomial over a field $F$ as a characteristic polynomial for a $F$-linear map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm considering $K/F$ to be an extension of degree $n$. I've shown that for any $a\in K$, the map $\mu_a : K → K$ deﬁned by $\mu_a(x) = ax$ for all $x\in K$, is a linear transformation of the $F$-vector space $K$. I'm now trying to show that $K$ is isomorphic to a subﬁeld of the ring $F^{n×n}$ of $n×n$ matrices with entries in $F$ and that $a$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $\mu_a$. Using this procedure I've to ﬁnd the monic polynomial satisﬁed by $1+ \sqrt 2+ 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$. How is this done? I think calculating the monic polynomial by squaring and cubing will be too cumbersome in this case. How do I do it using the given process?

Comment: As $\;K\;$ is commutative you could probably try to prove that it is a subfield of the *center* of $\;\Bbb F^{n\times n}\;$

Comment: Perhaps there's some particular trick here, though I doubt it: in the general case it looks like there's no way out of doing cumbersome calculations.